# Changing Content Editor Programatically - Client model API?

Tags: development, web-part, client-object-model, content-editor-web-part

Is it at all possible to make changes to or add a content editor to a page using only the Client Object Model API? There does not appear to be any reference to a ContentEditorWebPart dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the DLL as usual, you need to provide a [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WebParts.WebPart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.webparts.webpart.aspx), you can get this from [WebPartDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.webparts.webpartdefinition.aspx) which you again can get from [LimitedWebPartManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.webparts.limitedwebpartmanager.aspx).
Then you provide the correct definition, you can get this from exporting the Web Part.
You basically need `<Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>` and
        `<TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ContentEditorWebPart</TypeName>`.

Example:

```
var ctx = new ClientContext("http://localhost");
var page = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/default.aspx");
var wpm = page.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);
var webPartDefinition = wpm.ImportWebPart(@"
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
  <WebPart xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2'>
    <Title>Hello, Robert</Title>
    <Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>
    <TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ContentEditorWebPart</TypeName>
    <Content><![CDATA[<strong>The Wheel weaves as the Wheel wills</strong>]]></Content>
  </WebPart>");
wpm.AddWebPart(webPartDefinition.WebPart, "Main", 0);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```